# What RPG had space travel, star gates, and an organization maybe called "Brothers of Battle"?

Tags: product-identification, outer-space

I have some vague recollection of an RPG in the late 90s or early 2000s that had something like the following components:

- Space travel
- An interstellar empire, possible crumbling?
- Various organizations, including a martial (possibly religious?) order called something like "Brothers of Battle"
- Gates in outer space that either sped up your space ship or teleported you to other locations. There may have been some fluff hinting that each use of these gates snuffed out a star somewhere.

For a long time I thought this was the "Aeon" (later "Trinity") White Wolf title, but after re-reading about Trinity I doubt that it's the same. I'm wondering now if they were maybe just available at about the same time, especially since I remember the window where Aeon was still getting books released under that name.

Writing all of the above makes this sound like a Warhammer 40k title, but I don't remember it being related to Warhammer at all.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### This sounds a lot like [Fading Suns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fading_Suns).

In the game's setting, humanity has fallen into a dark age, where most of the population are technologically ignorant and superstitious, hoping that their religious beliefs will protect them from the terrifying realities of the universe (such at the fading of the stars). Starships and laser weapons coexist with medieval plate armor and swords.

I think the game has all of your points covered.

- PCs often travel from planet to planet on space craft, though that's not something the majority of the settings people get the chance to do.
- The dark age came about after the fall of the "Second Republic" hundreds of years in the past, though the fall persisted a lot longer than it might have because of political infighting between the Noble houses. The setting as of the Second Edition of the game was a bit optimistic that the worst was past, though, as a new Emperor had won the long-lasting civil wars and was beginning to stabilize things. One major campaign style is for the PCs to play "Questing Knights" (or one Questing Knight and their entourage of priests, guildsmen and hangers on) doing jobs in the name of the new Emperor.
- One of the religious factions in the game are the Brothers Battle, who are a militarized monastic order. They get access to some of the heaviest powered armor in the game (which may be why you're thinking about Warhammer 40k), and can layer on top of that supernatural protection from their battle prayers, if they have the appropriate training (and faith).
- FTL travel between systems happens at Jump Gates, created by ancient aliens with technology that humans have never fully understood (even in the golden age of the Second Republic).

The authors of Fading Suns had previously worked on the World of Darkness games for White Wolf, so it has a lot of stylistic similarities to those games.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you!